# Casting in VimScript/VimL

Tags: vimscript

Is there a syntax to cast from one character type for another? For example can you cast from a char to an int?

I tried:

```
let my_var = (int)some_char
```

It is not valid code.

Comment: It helps reading Vim's scripting help first ... To quote: `Vim automatically converts a string to a number when it is looking for a number.` If you want ASCII char conversion instead, see `char2nr()` and `nr2char()`.

Comment: And there's the `str2nr` function.

Comment: If you know it is a number, you can also simply add zero to it.

Comment: I'm not trying to parse it... Also I'm more wondering about casting in general. Casting from char to int is just one example.

Comment: http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/ (sections: "variables", "numbers" and "strings")

Comment: [`:help variables`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#variables)

Comment: It's not letting me post the answer because it is too simple. The answer is no.

Comment: I use `eval()` to convert a string into a number, and `string()` to convert in the reverse direction. I prefer `eval()` over `+0`, it makes the intends more obvious.

Comment: @VanLaser Thanks for reminding us that any time someone asks something that was revealed in the help it is completely impossible that they did not already look in the help. Obviously using Vim's help to look for anything at all is extremely easy and intuitive, and anyone searching for anything there would quickly be successful in finding and understand the information they are looking for. Now that I think about it, this website is not helpful at all, and should just be replaced with an issue tracker for ways Vim's help can be improved or added to...

Comment: So did you look in the help file, or you found it not so extremely easy and intuitive to read? Personally, I would *love* to see on this site questions that *don't* have an answer already given in Vim's help :)

Comment: @VanLaser the purpose of this website it not to provide questions that are personally entertaining for you to look at on the basis that they are completely untouched or unanswered in the manual. It is to help people with questions find people with answers. Asking questions where the answer is somehow provided or explained in the manual is not against the rules of this website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. There is no general syntax to cast from one type to another. There are unique ways of converting to different types, but no universal casting syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a round about way by first casting the float to a string then casting it to number for example:

`echom str2nr(string(log10(200)))`

Hope this helps people searching in the future.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! You haven't quite answered the question, which asked about character types (char and int), but thanks for sharing the knowledge!